# How to call a function from another route in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

im trying to call a function from another route in laravel php.

I have the route "welcome"

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

where im calling this extends (sidebar)

```
@extends('layouts.guestnavbar')
```

i want to see if my table notifications is empty or not so i made this controller

```
class GuestNavbarController extends Controller
{
    public function isempty(){
        $notif = Notification::first();
        if(is_null($notif)) {
            return view('layouts.guestnavbar')->with("checkempty", "empty");
        }else {
            return view('layouts.guestnavbar')->with("checkempty", "not empty");
        }
    }
}
```

and i called the variable `{{ $checkempty }}` in my route guestnavbar

```
Route::get('/guestnavbar', [GuestNavbarController::class, 'isempty']);
```

and it works when im in the route guestnavbar
but doesnt work when im in the route welcome because i call the function in the route guestnavbar and in welcome he doesnt recognize the variable: checkempty

i need this function to be in the guestnavbar because i have to call it on other pages, not just in welcome page

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Look into [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers), that will allow you to run methods any time the view is loaded

Answer (score 2):

You don't need isempty inside controller, just add method isempty inside Notification model, you can use something like this inside Notification model:

```
public static function isEmpty(){
    return Notification::first() ? true : false;
}
```

And then where you need to check if notification table is empty just call Notification::isEmpty()

Comment: I tried and it worked! Thank you.